# SQL Server : DATE or NULL Variable in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I am in the process of trying to amalgamate a pair of near identical queries, that use slightly different `WHERE` clauses depending on parameterised variables (Pipeline and Completions).

I am struggling to work out the best way to code it to look for either a date range or a NULL depending on the `@ReportMode` variable.

The `WHERE` clause in the first instance is essentially:

```
DECLARE @ReportMode VARCHAR(20),
        @ApplictnDate DATETIME;

SET @ApplictnDate = 
    CASE 
       WHEN @ReportMode = 'Completions' THEN '20160801 00:00:00'
       WHEN @ReportMode = 'Pipeline'    THEN '20170201 00:00:00'
    END        

SELECT 
    Id, AppDate, CompDate 
FROM 
    TbTable 
WHERE 
    AppDate > @ApplictnDate AND
    CompDate BETWEEN '20170701 00:00:00' AND '20170731 00:00:00'
```

With the second query being:

```
DECLARE @ReportMode VARCHAR(20),
        @ApplictnDate DATETIME;

SET @ApplictnDate = 
    CASE 
       WHEN @ReportMode = 'Completions' THEN '20160801 00:00:00'
       WHEN @ReportMode = 'Pipeline'    THEN '20170201 00:00:00'
    END        

SELECT 
    Id, AppDate, CompDate 
FROM 
    TbTable 
WHERE 
    AppDate > @ApplictnDate AND
    CompDate IS NULL
```

**Questions**:

1. Can I create a `CASE` statement within the `SELECT` statement using the variable or will it need to be `SET` as per `@ApplictnDate`?
2. How to I create the `CASE` statement syntactically to deal with a NULL or a date range?

Thanks

Comment: Just use an OR and () to keep the where statements as one unit?

Comment: Just to be nitpicky: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) in T-SQL - not a statement. It's something that gets evaluated to a single, atomic value.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not read or re-read [Sommaskogs blog post](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) recently, it is most certainly worth reading, to avoid the most typical performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

A CASE isn't needed for CompDate, you can use an OR.

But be aware that AND is evaluated before an OR.
F.e.  `a=1 OR b=1 AND c=1` evaluates as `a=1 OR (b=1 AND c=1)`, not `(a=1 OR b=1) AND c=1`
So include brackets to avoid the AND/OR pitfall.

```
DECLARE @ApplictnDate DATETIME = 
    CASE @ReportMode 
    WHEN 'Completions' THEN '2016-08-01' 
    WHEN 'Pipeline' THEN '2017-02-01' 
    END;

DECLARE @CompDateStart DATETIME = '2017-07-01';
DECLARE @CompDateEnd DATETIME = EOMONTH(@CompDateStart);

SELECT Id,
       AppDate,
       CompDate 
FROM TbTable 
WHERE AppDate > @ApplictnDate
 AND (CompDate IS NULL OR CompDate BETWEEN @CompDateStart AND @CompDateEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against a single query. It's possible but the query processor will cache the first version it encounters but there will likely be better plans for each of null and non null values. Likely you will hit performance issues as a result.

A better approach would be separate queries or procedures for each case. If you're (quite rightly) trying to avoid repetition do the predicate and parameter-free query as a view then separate procedures/queries with different `WHERE` clauses and application of parameters.